# Django Not Found: /polls/style.css how can i fix it?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

hi i changed my code to style.css but the change site was not it confused me maybe i am doing something wrong look at my code below and draw your own conclusion, I hope for a good answer

Console Log:

```
PS C:\Users\kostia_admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject32\mysite>  python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\kostia_admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject32\mysite\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
June 17, 2022 - 17:16:44
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[17/Jun/2022 17:16:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3536
Not Found: /polls/static/polls/images/style.css
[17/Jun/2022 17:16:46] "GET /polls/static/polls/images/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2895
Not Found: /polls/style.css
[17/Jun/2022 17:16:46] "GET /polls/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2835
```

index.html(I think there's a mistake here. ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/polls/style.css" type="text/css" />

        <title>Shop</title>



    </head>
    <body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-logo">
            <h1 class="logo">SunRise Donate shop</h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="header-navigation">
            <a href="https://sunmc.ru/">About</a>
            <a href="https://sunmc.ru/main/different/" class="link-button">Diferent<i class="material-icons-outlined"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="responsive-container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-column">
                                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://reallyworld.ru/images/privileges/hero.webp" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">HERO</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://reallyworld.ru/images/privileges/ghelper.webp" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">GOD</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 9</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/wither.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">WITHER</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 9</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-column">
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/phoenix.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">PHOENIX</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 9</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/avenger.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">AVENGER</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 12</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/legend.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">LEGEND</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-column">
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/phantom.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">PHANTOM</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 15</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="product" href="#">
                    <div class="product-image">
                        <img src="https://sunmc.ru/source/img/supreme.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h2 class="product-title">SUPREME</h2>
                            <p class="product-price">$ 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
style.css:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, ul, ol, li, figure, figcaption, blockquote, dl, dd {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input, button, textarea, select {
  font: inherit;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: transparent;
}
body {
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}
.responsive-container {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  min-height: 60px;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2000px;
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.header-navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.header-navigation a {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.link-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fa3450;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
  color: #fff;
}
.link-button i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;

}
main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
}
.grid-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid-column > * + * {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.product {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product:hover, .product:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.21rem Green;
}
.product:hover .product-content, .product:focus .product-content {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.product-image {
  border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product-content {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.25rem 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: #F43FF;
}
.product-action {
  color: #043242300;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.product-action:hover {
  background-color: #e5ffeb;
}
.product-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.product-title {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.product-price {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}
.credits {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  color: #7577;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.credits a {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    gap: 1.5rem;
  }
  .grid-column > * + * {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
  }


}
```

Could you reformat my code to correct the errors?
I think I made a mistake somewhere very simple (I'm new to django so don't judge)

Comment: where are your static files, which directory?

Comment: css sources are of no use here. please show settings.py, urls.py `href="/polls/style.css"` nope, please follow the docs, they are pretty clear about how to refer to static files.

Comment: `GET /polls/static/polls/images/style.css` this does not match shown html code.